# How to write unit test for DataTable in React Component using Enzyme with Jest?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to React Unit testing. I had built a React Component that renders a [DataTable](http://datatables.net), which takes `column names` and `data` as props. I had written unit test for table element using Enzyme with Jest, which is `PASSED`. Unit Test is

```
describe('Client Component Testing', () => {

    let mountedClientComp;
    const clientComp = () => {
        if (!mountedClientComp) {
            mountedClientComp = mount(
                <ClientsTable/>
            );
        }
        return mountedClientComp;
    };

    it('Client component renders a table', () => {
        const table = clientComp();
        table.setState({ temp: true });
        table.update();
        expect(table.exists('table')).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

But am not getting, how to write unit test for DataTable Search Field, Pagination buttons, Table Info, Table Length, Sorting elements.

DataTable manipulates DOM by taking `table` html tag into DataTable object, and since `table` html tag is written in React component, unit test for table element `PASSED`.

But for testing DataTable Search input field, am finding `input` element, which is not written and which will be dynamically appended, so am not getting how to write unit test!?

How to write unit test for dynamically added elements?

Regards [Shashidhar]

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a new `<ClientsTable>` in each test case with different properties and in those respective test case find whatever you want.